# How do I display content from feedburner in WebView in Full HTML?

Tags: android, hyperlink, webview, settings, user-agent

I am using a `WebView` to display this [feedburner](http://feeds.feedburner.com/fsn). When I view this link in Google Chrome and in the device's browser it shows the title, snippet, links, and most importantly a podcast file and other hyperlinks. However, when I view this link in my `WebView` it only shows it in Plain Text HTML with no hyperlinks.  All i see is a title and the story snippet, followed by HTML source code. Is there a particular that must be enabled to resolve this?

These are my `WebView` settings:

```
newsfeed = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewnews);
newsfeed.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
newsfeed.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
newsfeed.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

How I load the URL:

```
try {
    newsfeed.loadUrl("http://feeds.feedburner.com/fsn");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: does it show correctly in the stock browser on the device?

Comment: how do you load the content into the webView?

Comment: @Tim it shows perfectly fine in the device's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing what you are seeing, list of entries with Title followed by html of article content on the Stock Browser - Motorola Droid running 2.2.3. My guess is that this is the format that the site provided for the stock Android WebView User Agent. Google Chrome is NOT the stock browser that comes with Android Open Source Project and does more under the hood to render content.

I would try a different user agent first to see if the webview will render the content. Note that they may be using various Javascript libraries which don't work well with Android which is why you are seeing the 'simplified' content.

Comment: I'm a relative noob to Android. What exactly is a user agent? and how do i switch them?

Comment: A user agent is what the client sends to the server to identify itself. Depending of what the client is, the server can either return a feature rich or poor response. You can set the user agent in the WebSettings class.