# Why is my WebView displaying rss in Plain Text HTML?

Tags: android, html, url, webview, plaintext

I am a noob to android and i am having a very similar issue to the issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821233/how-do-i-display-content-from-feedburner-in-webview-in-full-html).  I am having trouble displaying feedburner content as well.  it shows the feed in plain text and it is unreadable because of all the html tags.  i tried the suggestion in the posted answer but it didn't help. Could i somehow use loadData instead and surround the url with "html".  is that possible? Any help is appreciated.

```
huffingtonpost = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    try{
    huffingtonpost.loadUrl("http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoldMoneyGoldResearch");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that happens because the page returned by `http://feeds.feedburner.com/GoldMoneyGoldResearch` is not in HTML format, it's in RSS XML format.

If you want to format it into HTML, you can use XML parser to extract entries from RSS XML and convert them into HTML. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android) is a brief example of extracting data from RSS.